# Send existing multidimensional array via POST

Tags: php, arrays, post, multidimensional-array

On my page I have a multidimensional array which I need to pass to another page, and from that page I'm going to send the array to controller. The array will be always hidden to simplify a form.
 I searched a little but didn't find an answer to my question.
So it looks like this

```
<form action="index.php?route=common/fittingForm" method="post">
    <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="products[]" value="<?php echo $product; ?>" >
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Buy" class="buy_button">
</form>
```

And the page that gets the array looks like this

```
<?php $products = $_POST["products"]; ?>
<?php
    foreach($products as $product)
        echo $product['model'];
 ?>
```

And of course everything doesn't work. And I don't know why.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: another page to me means a separate request. is your situation all within the same request?

Comment: Well, I pass the array to first page (1 request), the from the first page I send the array to controller. So two request. Sorry, if I didn't understand your question, my english isn't flawless.

Comment: well if it's 2 or more requests ie a redirect, then you have to store the array in somewhere like `$_SESSION`, db or a file.

Answer (score 2):

Encode it to JSON before you send it :

```
<form action="index.php?route=common/fittingForm" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="products" value="<?php echo json_encode($products);?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Buy" class="buy_button">
</form>
```

and decode it :

```
<?php
$products = json_decode($_POST["products"]);
    foreach($products as $product)
        echo $product['model'];
?>
```

Comment: I get an error after I press submit button "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\apache\localhost\www\webshop.kg\catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\fittingForm.tpl on line 3". Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: OH sorry i forget to notice you to decode it before ...
i have updated my answer